# Is there a plugin for saving/loading registers' contents to/from files in a convenient way?

Tags: register, plugin

**tl;dr**

Is there a Vim plugin that allows me to save/load registers to/from files with minimal typing, preview of registers, and other amenities?

---

**Long version**

Vim has a lot of registers. However, the "only" ones that serve a "storage" purpose are registers `a` to `z`. Indeed

- only the user can edit them and only by explicitly naming them (whereas numbered registers change, or actually shift, automatically),
- they don't affect and are not affected by the "outside world" (`+` and `*` do affect and are affected by what happens outside of Vim),
- they have no special behavior (`_` is the black hole, `"` is the last used register, and so on).

Now, for me it's natural to resort to `a`-`z` registers when I want to put stuff there that I might reuse several times during a workday. However, the various usages often depends on what I'm doing.

There are times when I'm debugging C++ code, that I often need to efficiently (from they keystroke standapoint) load the same, say, 4 or 5 dynamic libraries everytime I restart the debug session, so it's very useful to have those libraries (or the whole line for gdb `-exec shared somelibrary.so`) in the registers.

Much less often, but still not only once in a lifetime, there are times when I'm doing some text editing that requires that I run the same few macros I run a month ago.

It would be nice to have registers' contents saved in "databases". For instance, having a file named `dynamicLibrariesLoadCmds.txt` with content such as

```
a: -exec shared somelibrary.so
b: -exec shared someotherlibrary.so
q: -exec shared onemorelib.so
```

and then some command to load all those lines into the appropriate registers.

Is there a plugin that provides such a functionality?

Comment: It sounds like you actually need a clipboard manager with bookmarks/favorites instead of a vim plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function that achieves your goal, but it assumes that the text to the right of `:`  is properly formatted for Vim (so your examples all need quotes to make strings). It does incidentally mean that the content can be an arbitrary vimscript expression :) this latter could be a security bug, so only load databases you trust. Alternately, change `parts[1]` and `{content}` to `string(parts[1])` and `{string(content)}`, respectively, avoiding the need for quotes or any security holes from evaluating the content. (Executing the register as a macro would still, obviously, be vulnerable.)

```
function ReadReg(file) abort
  eval readfile(a:file)
      \ ->map({_, line -> split(line, ': ')})
      \ ->map({_, parts -> execute(printf(':let @%s = %s', parts[0], parts[1]))})
endfunction
```

In vim9:

```
vim9script
def ReadReg(file: string)
  readfile(file)->mapnew((_, line) => {
    var [reg, content] = split(line, ': ')
    execute $'@{reg} = {content}'
  })
enddef
```

Then you could bind a `:command` if you wanted.

Comment: `all need quotes to make strings` Could make use of `:h string()` function to add proper quoting, like `printf('let @%s = %s', parts[0], string(parts[1]))`. `content can be an arbitrary vimscript expression` A potential security bug?

Comment: Agreed on both fronts; wasn't aware of string @Matt. I will make both more explicit.

Comment: oof, forgot about `setreg`. The `execute` could probably be removed with that.

Answer (score 1):

Register contents already saved into viminfo file. But you can create some sort of "extra spare file" if you wish.

Here is (almost) one-liner:

```
call split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '\zs')
  \ ->filter('!empty(getreg(v:val))')
  \ ->map('printf("call setreg(%s, %s)",
  \     string(v:val), string(getreginfo(v:val)))')
  \ ->writefile('myregs.vim')
```

And then `:source myregs.vim` to restore them.